# What tool to edit the /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml file

Tags: mime-types, icons

I edited my /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml (with a text editor) to modify the file icon of application/x-7z-compressed mime type :

```
<mime-type type="application/x-7z-compressed">
  <generic-icon name="package-x-generic"/>
```

I would like to know if there is a tool to edit this file (or to change the icon of a mime type) instead of using a text editor ?

**EDIT:** My aim is to script my modifications of the freedesktop.org.xml file, so that an text editor is not appropriate.
I would like a command-line tool to edit the `name` attribut of the `generic-icon` tag of a chosen MIME type.

**EDIT:** As @Gilles pointed it to me, it should be better to modify the `$XDG_DATA_HOME/mime/packages/Override.xml` file instead of `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml` file. But this does not really change my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use whatever XML library is available in your language of choice to modify such XML document programatically. In python for instance is available https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html

Comment: So no tool, but I can do the tool myself ;)

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml` is the [Freedesktop MIME database](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec). The web page lists many tools to query this database, and a few to modify it.

You should not be modifying this file manually: files under `/usr` but outside `/usr/local` are managed by your distribution's package manager, and your modifications would be overwritten on the next upgrade. Instead, write your own file in `/usr/local/share/mime/packages`, or `somedir/packages` where `somedir` is any other directory listed in `$XDG_PATH`. When you've modified the file, run `update-mime-database /usr/local/share/mime/packages` to update the cache (you need to run [`update-mime-database`](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/shared-mime-info) anyway, since applications read the binary cache and not the XML files).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you gave me a link to a list of programs that indeed query the mime database but which one allow to modify the file icon of a mime type? For instance MIME-editor allow to edit a bit the mime database but I didn't find how to modify the file icon of a mime type.

Answer (score 0):

The point with XML is that you should be able to edit it manually, with an editor, and also view it (if necessary) without any surplus software.

This is one of the advantages of XML. Even the Lisp people want to take credit for XML, claiming its unrestricted way to markup data is a reinvention of the Lisp associative list (or `alist`) data structure.

But, although strictly speaking not necessary, you might want additional software in some cases. For example, in the Unix/Linux world, a common tool to do diagrams, state machine illustrations, and so on, is Dia. In Dia, when you draw diagrams, you use their GUI. But what you see is just a GFX representation of how your drawings are represented internally - as XML. This is a good example when it makes little sense using an editor editing and viewing XML: although it would be perfectly possible, it wouldn't be practical.

However, in your case, you are not drawing anything or doing anything that would motivate a GUI interface. So an editor is just fine. If you use Emacs, the `.xml` extension will automatically put you in the right mode if you open the file. An advanced editor will give you highlighting and indentation, as well as some more advanced features that you'll discover along the way.

Comment: I would like to have a tool to script the modifications I want to do, this way it will be easy to modify the freedesktop.org.xml file. While without an appropriate tool I have to edit the XML file with an XML library in a more powerful language than bash.

Comment: @Nicolas: I'm not following 100% - would you like a command (shortcut) that modifies the file?

Comment: Absolutly, I need a program to modify the freedesktop.org.xml file. because I want to create an installation script that modifies the freedesktop.org.xml file and it would be easier for me to call a program that does the job instead of parsing and modifying myself the XML file.